# when will it be safe to develop for CSS3

Tags: css

i'm beginning a new site and i want to use CSS3 features but i don't want to start something if its not in or going to be widely used

Comment: This depends on your target market

Comment: Its fairly widely used now... I use box-shadow, border-radius, and gradients all the time. You use what you can where it makes sense. Google "progressive enhancement"

Answer (score 3):

There are varying levels of support for various features, and browsers are being pretty good about keeping support in vendor prefix properties until specifications stabilize.

So long you build with progressive enhancement in mind, it is safe now.